# Could I create a bot in the Enterprise intranet to connect to Lync?

Tags: botframework, lync, skype-for-business

The example in MS Official website is a skybot and needs to register it to Bot Framework developer portal before using it.

Is it possible to connect my bot and Microsoft Lync/Skype for Business in the intranet directly?

How do I do?

Comment: Using the Bot Builder SDK it might be problematic. But the Bot Connector is a public service, so as long as your service has an endpoint that the connector can reach, you can implement anything. (However, for using the connector you do have to register your bot on the official MS website.) More details of your use case would be helpful.

Comment: Thank your comment. For security issue, it is impossible to have a endpoint opening for internet accessing. It's why we desire a intranet only bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No its not possible.

Firstly, lync is not a valid channel for the framework (Skype for Business isn't either,but it seems like the devs [might be working on adding Skype for Business](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/565))

[vote to add skype for business here](https://feedback.botframework.com/forums/354219-bot-connector/suggestions/13223985-any-plans-for-skype-for-business)

They also aren't planning on creating Enterprise only bots [source](http://docs.botframework.com/en-us/faq/#is-it-possible-for-me-to-build-a-bot-using-the-bot-frameworksdk-that-is-a-private-or-enterprise-only-bot-that-is-only-available-inside-my-company)